# oracle function to return list of dates as object

Tags: oracle, function, object, plsql, types

To whom it may respond to ,

I am trying to return list of dates and weekdays to be used in other functions. Code below is compiled without error. But it should give output of 15 days (via V_MAX_DAYS variable) and number of the day in that week.

I have tried to implement like this, but cannot get output using DBMS_OUTPUT. I want to test it but got ORA-06532 error at  when running .
My aim is to return values to asp.net application as we have done using SYS_REFCURSOR. 
How can I achieve that?
Thank you for your concern,

The script is as below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DATE_ROW AS OBJECT
(
  WEEKDAY_VALUE DATE,
  DATE_IN_LIST VARCHAR2(5)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DATE_TABLE as table of DATE_ROW
/



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_LISTDATES
   RETURN DATE_TABLE
IS
   V_DATE_TABLE        DATE_TABLE    := DATE_TABLE ();
   V_MAX_DAYS          NUMBER        := 15;
   V_CALCULATED_DATE   DATE;
   V_WEEKDAY           VARCHAR2 (5);
BEGIN
   FOR X IN -2 .. V_MAX_DAYS
   LOOP
      SELECT TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE + X, 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
        INTO V_CALCULATED_DATE
        FROM DUAL;
      V_DATE_TABLE.EXTEND;
      V_DATE_TABLE(X) := DATE_ROW(V_CALCULATED_DATE, 'Test');
   END LOOP;
   RETURN V_DATE_TABLE;
END;
/
```

Comment: If you want to get output from PL/SQL, you need to set serveroutput: `set serveroutput on`.

Comment: I am going with TOAD 9.6.0.27

Comment: FWFD, any recommendations for test case? So far I understand that you offer me to test it using SQLPlus console. BTW, I guess I should try it with pipelined table functions since 20 rows is not much. But it is going to be called for every logged in user to the web site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points.

1. If you want a DATE (V_CALCULATED_DATE) that is X days from SYSDATE with the time component set to midnight, which appears to be your intent here, you would want something like `v_calculated_date := TRUNC(sysdate) + x;`.  A TO_DATE without an explicit format mask is going to create issues if a future session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT happens not to be DD.MM.YYYY
2. If you really want to return a collection like this, your collection indexes would need to start with 1, not -2.  You could accomplish that by doing `v_date_table(x+3) := DATE_ROW(v_calculated_date, 'Test');`.
3. However, I would tend to suspect that you would be better served here with a pipelined table function.

The pipelined table function would look something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_LISTDATES
  2     RETURN DATE_TABLE
  3     PIPELINED
  4  IS
  5     V_MAX_DAYS          NUMBER        := 15;
  6     V_CALCULATED_DATE   DATE;
  7     V_WEEKDAY           VARCHAR2 (5);
  8  BEGIN
  9     FOR X IN -2 .. V_MAX_DAYS
 10     LOOP
 11        v_calculated_date := trunc(sysdate) + x;
 12        PIPE ROW( DATE_ROW(v_calculated_date,'Test') );
 13     END LOOP;
 14     RETURN;
 15* END;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select * from table( fn_listDates );

WEEKDAY_V DATE_
--------- -----
30-NOV-10 Test
01-DEC-10 Test
02-DEC-10 Test
03-DEC-10 Test
04-DEC-10 Test
05-DEC-10 Test
06-DEC-10 Test
07-DEC-10 Test
08-DEC-10 Test
09-DEC-10 Test
10-DEC-10 Test

WEEKDAY_V DATE_
--------- -----
11-DEC-10 Test
12-DEC-10 Test
13-DEC-10 Test
14-DEC-10 Test
15-DEC-10 Test
16-DEC-10 Test
17-DEC-10 Test

18 rows selected.
```

Comment: Mr. Cave, works like a charm.. Thank you for your concern and time,